# External login fails asp.net mvc core 2.2

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Did scaffold some identity pages (Login, Logout, Register) for translation purposes and added Google as an external provider. It works, but when I hit Register on the Identity/Account/ExternalLogin page I get the following error:

InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'IdentityUserLogin' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'LoginProvider', 'ProviderKey'} is already being tracked.

Did scaffold ExternalLogin to check what might be wrong: here is the (standard) code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostConfirmationAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
    // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
    var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (info == null)
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Error loading external login information during confirmation.";
        return RedirectToPage("./Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            result = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            ...
```

The await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info) gives the exception mentioned.

```
    InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'LoginProvider', 'ProviderKey'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap<TKey>.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap<TKey>.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry, bool updateDuplicate)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap<TKey>.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NullableKeyIdentityMap<TKey>.Add(InternalEntityEntry entry)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, bool acceptChanges)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, bool acceptChanges, Nullable<EntityState> forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode node, bool force)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph<TState>(EntityEntryGraphNode node, TState state, Func<EntityEntryGraphNode, TState, bool> handleNode)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState entityState, bool forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState entityState)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState<TEntity>(TEntity entity, EntityState entityState)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Add<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet<TEntity>.Add(TEntity entity)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore<TUser, TContext, TKey, TUserClaim, TUserLogin, TUserToken>.AddLoginAsync(TUser user, UserLoginInfo login, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<TUser>.AddLoginAsync(TUser user, UserLoginInfo login)
Project.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.ExternalLoginModel.OnPostConfirmationAsync(string returnUrl) in ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs
+
   result = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
```

How to solve this? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: That's an EF Core error, It complains that you tried to add/attach an entity with the same key as an entity that was loaded from the database. This isn't about authentication. Post your code.

Comment: That's right, a well known one, but in this case I don't see what went wrong.

Comment: I explained one possibility. One can only guess without the code though. The only thing that's certain is that this is not about authentication

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Provided the code where the problem occurs

Comment: You didn't post the exception though. Post the *full* exception, including the call stack. You can get that easily with `Exception.ToString()`. This will show any nested exceptions and most importantly, the actual calls that threw the exception. I suspect `AddLoginAsync` throws because it's trying to *create* a new user and finds that the context already has that user

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The user is not in the database, the create adds the user to the database, but your right, there was an associated entry in AspNetUserLogins

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have a similar problem and I suspect it's because  `DbContext` and `UserManager` are interfering with each other.

Comment: Like I said, there still was an active user in the table AspNetUsersLogin. Remove it.